# To Run multiple commands on different servers (taken from a text file) using shell script and writing the output to another file

Tags: shell

Sorry for the trouble.. here is the code what works for a single server. I need help to loop it to multiple servers. Thanks in advance, Please help me out .

I need to know information of multiple servers like their:

```
Operating system info
Hostname and dns info
Network info
Who is online
Last logged in users and so on
```

logic is to pass the server names from a text file and display the same info for all the server in the file and write output to other file

Below are the different fucntions which fetch the details of a server. The same should be iterated for multiple servers..

```
#!/bin/bash
# grabsysinfo.sh - A simple menu driven shell script to to get information about your 
# Linux server / desktop.

# Define variables
LSB=/usr/bin/lsb_release

# Purpose: Display pause prompt
# $1-> Message (optional)
function pause(){
local message="$@"
[ -z $message ] && message="Press [Enter] key to continue..."
read -p "$message" readEnterKey
}

# Purpose - Display a menu on screen
function show_menu(){
date
echo "---------------------------"
echo " Main Menu"
echo "---------------------------"
echo "1. Operating system info"
echo "2. Hostname and dns info"
echo "3. Network info"
echo "4. Who is online"
echo "5. Last logged in users"
echo "6. Free and used memory info"
echo "7. exit"
}

# Purpose - Display header message
# $1 - message
function write_header(){
local h="$@"
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------"
echo " ${h}"
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------"
}

# Purpose - Get info about your operating system
function os_info(){
write_header " System information "
echo "Operating system : $(uname)"
[ -x $LSB ] && $LSB -a || echo "$LSB command is not insalled (set \$LSB variable)"
#pause "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
pause
}

# Purpose - Get info about host such as dns, IP, and hostname
local dnsips=$(sed -e '/^$/d' /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{if (tolower($1)=="nameserver") print $2}')
write_header " Hostname and DNS information "
echo "Hostname : $(hostname -s)"
echo "DNS domain : $(hostname -d)"
echo "Fully qualified domain name : $(hostname -f)"
echo "Network address (IP) : $(hostname -i)"
echo "DNS name servers (DNS IP) : ${dnsips}"
pause
}

# Purpose - Network inferface and routing info
function net_info(){
devices=$(netstat -i | cut -d" " -f1 | egrep -v "^Kernel|Iface|lo")
write_header " Network information "
echo "Total network interfaces found : $(wc -w <<<${devices})"

echo "*** IP Addresses Information ***"
ip -4 address show

echo "***********************"
echo "*** Network routing ***"
echo "***********************"
netstat -nr

echo "**************************************"
echo "*** Interface traffic information ***"
echo "**************************************"
netstat -i

pause 
}

# Purpose - Display a list of users currently logged on 
# display a list of receltly loggged in users 
function user_info(){
local cmd="$1"
case "$cmd" in 
who) write_header " Who is online "; who -H; pause ;;
last) write_header " List of last logged in users "; last ; pause ;;
esac 
}

# Purpose - Display used and free memory info
function mem_info(){
write_header " Free and used memory "
free -m

echo "*********************************"
echo "*** Virtual memory statistics ***"
echo "*********************************"
vmstat
echo "***********************************"
echo "*** Top 5 memory eating process ***"
echo "***********************************" 
ps auxf | sort -nr -k 4 | head -5 
pause
}
# Purpose - Get input via the keyboard and make a decision using case..esac 
function read_input(){
local c
read -p "Enter your choice [ 1 - 7 ] " c
case $c in
1) os_info ;;
2) host_info ;;
3) net_info ;;
4) user_info "who" ;;
5) user_info "last" ;;
6) mem_info ;;
7) echo "Bye!"; exit 0 ;;
*) 
echo "Please select between 1 to 7 choice only."
pause
esac
}

# ignore CTRL+C, CTRL+Z and quit singles using the trap
trap '' SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTSTP
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need Key-Based SSH login to your remote servers ([https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Key-Based_SSH_Logins](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Key-Based%5fSSH%5fLogins))

After that you use a loop like this:

```
function read_input(){
    read -p "Enter your choice [ 1 - 7 ] " c
    for server in $(cat your_server_file);
    do
        case $c in
          1) os_info $server;;
          2) host_info $server;;
          3) net_info $server;;
          4) user_info "who" $server;;
          5) user_info "last" $server;;
          6) mem_info $server;;
          7) echo "Bye!"; exit 0 ;;
          *) 
              echo "Please select between 1 to 7 choice only."
              pause
              esac
   done
}
```

And in example your `mem_info` function

```
function mem_info(){
    server=$1
    write_header " Free and used memory "
    ssh ssh_remote_user@server free -m
    echo "*********************************"
    echo "*** Virtual memory statistics ***"
    echo "*********************************"
    ssh ssh_remote_user@server vmstat
    echo "***********************************"
    echo "*** Top 5 memory eating process ***"
    echo "***********************************" 
    ssh ssh_remote_user@server ps auxf | sort -nr -k 4 | head -5 
    pause
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you use `sshpass` you have to change a little bit.

Your `your_server_file` should look like this:

```
user1@password1|user1@server1
user2@password2|user2@server2
 ...
```

Your main function

```
function read_input(){
    read -p "Enter your choice [ 1 - 7 ] " c
    for line in $(cat your_server_file);
    do
        user_pass=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/\(.*\)|\(.*\)/\1/')
        server=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/\(.*\)|\(.*\)/\2/')
        case $c in
          1) os_info $server $user;;
          2) host_info $server $user;;
          3) net_info $server $user;;
          4) user_info "who" $server $user;;
          5) user_info "last" $server $user;;
          6) mem_info $server $user;;
          7) echo "Bye!"; exit 0 ;;
          *) 
              echo "Please select between 1 to 7 choice only."
              pause
              esac
   done
}
```

And the mem_info function

```
function mem_info(){
    server=$1
    user_pass=$2
    write_header " Free and used memory "
    sshpass -p $user_pass ssh $server free -m
    echo "*********************************"
    echo "*** Virtual memory statistics ***"
    echo "*********************************"
    sshpass -p $user_pass ssh $server vmstat
    echo "***********************************"
    echo "*** Top 5 memory eating process ***"
    echo "***********************************" 
    sshpass -p $user_pass ssh $server ps auxf | sort -nr -k 4 | head -5 
    pause
}
```

I did not quote anything. Please take care about special characters

Comment: You can also use `sshpass` if you don't want to use the key-based login

Comment: sshpass will not require password to be entered each time , i guess. so my your_server_file should just be like user1@IP1,user2@IP2,... ?

Comment: Thanks @drkunubar ! wil execute and update you about result .